# RxJS's lettable operators breaks generic typings?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have  a basic Angular  [HttpIntereceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which returns `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
        {
            return  next.handle(req);
        }
```

This is working fine.

I wanted to add a side effect function so I used `.do` operator :

```
 return  next.handle(req).do(f=> ()=>{/*.somethinbg.*/});
```

This also  works.

But now I wanted to use the lettable operator `tap` which is the replacement of `do`.

So I did this:

```
 log =  tap(x =>{}, x =>{});
```

But now , when I'm *"letting"* it , I get an error :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I use this lettable operator and still keep generics/types ?

[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fu3nou?file=app/1.ts)

*Update:*

If I do this instead:

```
  return  next.handle(req).let( tap(x =>{}, x =>{}));
```

Then it does work. It's only when the function is outside , it makes errors.

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you currently using? There are known issues when it comes to type inference when using a TypeScript version <2.4.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `pipe` instead of `let`? what are your ts/rxjs versions?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo `pipe` is instead of `s$.let(a).let(b).let(c)` , so `s$.pipe(a,b,c)` is the replacement

Comment: Ts 2.42 , Rx 5.5

Comment: please see my edit.

Comment: [**DEMO ONLINE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fu3nou?file=app/1.ts)

Comment: Oh I see, havent used that operator

Comment: @Jota.Toledo update : there is no more `let` operation in rxjs5.5+ . Only `pipe` should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the type you want to use in `pipe` (or `let`) cannot be inferred when your custom operator is defined.

You can get around this limitation by using a more generic definition.

```
const log = <T>() => tap<T>(x => { });
```

I've also forked your DEMO to show this in action. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyeo3i?file=app/1.ts)

Comment: Re reading this ? How come T is inferred from the type of the "inside the let scope"?

Comment: I think this is because of contextual types as explained here. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html